How can I evaluate the Gaussian Integral using power series?
It's a well known result that the Gaussian integral
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$
evaluates to $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$. This result can be obtained using double integrals with polar coordinates, among other things, but I'm particularly interested in evaluating this integral using power series.
The power series of $e^{-x^2}$ is
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{n!}$$
and integrating this, we get
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(n!) (2n+1)}$$
This expression is our integral (and it also has a radius of convergence of infinity, so we know it’ll approximate our integral function everywhere), so to evaluate it, we plug in our bounds. The expression is 0 for the bound of 0, so we're just looking for the limit of this power series as it tends to infinity.
Using graphing software, with enough terms from the power series, I can see that the function does indeed spend a while at $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$ before diverging.
So, how can I analytically prove that the limit of the power series
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(n!) (2n+1)}$$
as $x$ approaches infinity is $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$?
Thanks for your help!

There is a fundamental problem with $\pi$;  where ever it emerges in a complex  contour integral, at least one power of $1/pi $ by Cauchys integral formula is involved, just by the length of the unit circle. Instead of searching for two different series for $\sqrt \pi$,  it's much more natural to work with the the inverse square of the series to  find a limit of $\pi$. In this sense the square of the Gaussian is the natural way to determine its value.

Contours that are conformal similar to the  unit circle by an analytical map.  In the complex plane the real line, in fact any line,  is a greatest circle passing over $a=b=\infty$

Note that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(n!) (2n+1)} = x\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_{n}}{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)_{n}}\frac{(-x^2)^n}{n!} = xM\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2},-x^2\right)$$
where $M(\cdot)$ is the confluent hypergeometric function.
Now from the Kummer's transformation:
$$xM\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2},-x^2\right)= xe^{-x^2}M\left(1,\frac{3}{2},x^2\right)$$
Finally, from the asymptotic behavior of the confluent hypergeometric function:
$$M\left(a,b,z\right)\sim\frac{\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma\left(a\right)}e^{z}z^{a-b} \quad (\Re(z)\to \infty); \; -\frac{3\pi}{2}<\arg{z}\leq \frac{\pi}{2};\;a\neq0,-1,-2,...$$
This is the same asymptotic in 13.2.23. Just notice that by 13.2.4
$$M\left(a,b,z\right)=\Gamma\left(b\right){\mathbf{M}}\left(a,b,z\right)$$
Hence
$$\boxed{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(n!) (2n+1)}= xe^{-x^2}M\left(1,\frac{3}{2},x^2\right) \sim \Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2},\quad  (x\to \infty)}$$
So
$$ \boxed{\lim_{x \to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(n!) (2n+1)} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}} $$

Of course, we need to know the value of $\Gamma(\frac32)$ without using $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$

Hi @GEdgar. From the definition of the gamma function $\displaystyle  \Gamma(z) = \frac{e^{-\gamma z}} z \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1 + \frac z n \right)^{-1} e^{z/n}$ and $\displaystyle \sin(z) = z\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)$ is easy to show that $\displaystyle \Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}$. Then with $\displaystyle z = \frac{1}{2}$ we get $\displaystyle  \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) =\sqrt{\pi}$. Finally, using $\displaystyle \Gamma(1+z) = z\Gamma(z)$ we get $\displaystyle \Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$

Using such a series would require a lot of terms.
But
$$x=\sqrt{-\log (1-t)}\quad \implies \quad I=\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx =\frac{1}{2} \int\limits_0^1 \frac{dt}{\sqrt{-\log(1-t)}}$$ Now, using series
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{-\log(1-t)}}=\frac 1{\sqrt t} \,\,\Bigg(1-\frac 14\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {a_n}{b_n}\, t^n\Bigg)$$ where the $a_n$  are given as sequences $A077230$  in $OEIS$ (take their absolute values).
The $b_n$ do not seem to correspond to any known sequence. The first are
$$\{1,24,32,7680,10240,15482880,61931520,29727129600,\cdots\}$$
The convergence is still quite slow : using $100$ terms, converted to decimals, the result is $\color{red}{0.88}43$.
What you could also write is
$$I=\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx =\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^{\sqrt{n}}\left(1 - \frac{x^2}{n}\right)^n dx
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{n} \int_0^1 \left(1 - t^2\right)^n dt$$ that is to say
$$I= \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{n}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\binom{n}{k}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{n} \,\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}\,\frac{\Gamma (n+1)}{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}$$ Now, taking logarithms and using Stirling approximation and exponentiation again
$$\sqrt{n} \,\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}\,\frac{\Gamma (n+1)}{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}\,\left( 1-\frac{3}{8 n}+\frac{25}{128 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)$$

There is a $dt$ on second equation?

@VincenzoTibullo. Thanks for pointing it !

But Mathematica starts with $1/\sqrt{t}$

The second equation, as stated and explained by using such OEIS sequences, seems to be wrong, Moreover, RHS is 0 when $t=0$, while LHS is $+\infty$

@VincenzoTibullo. This is what happens (too often) when my wife is not here to reread (I am blind and this is not an excuse). Thanks for pointing a cheers :-)

We can prove that

Theorem. We have
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!(2n+1)} x^{2n+1} = \sqrt{\frac{W}{2}}, $$
where $W$ is defined by
$$ W = \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{4k^2}{4k^2 - 1}. $$

Then OP's question is resolved by noting that $W = \frac{\pi}{2}$ according to the Wallis product, although the proof that I'm going to present doesn't rely on this fact. This solution is particularly aimed at proving the above relation with minimal use of the integral representation, focusing more on manipulating power series.
However, I should warn you that the proof is by no means easy – we'll need to get our hands a bit dirty with some nontrivial estimates.

First, we denote the power series in question by $f(x)$:
$$ f(x) = \int_{0}^{x} e^{-t^2} \, \mathrm{d}t = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{n!(2n+1)}. $$
Our aim is to show that $f(x) \to \sqrt{W/2}$ as $x \to \infty$. As the starting point of our quest, we prove:

Lemma 1. (Dawson function) We have
$$ f(x) = e^{-x^2} D(x), \qquad\text{where}\quad D(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^n}{(2n+1)!!} x^{2n+1}. $$

This allows us to circumvent the nasty issue of alternating signs in the power series expansion of $f(x)$, which renders the direct study of $f(x)$ extremely hard.
Now, instead of proving the above lemma right here, let me defer the proof to the end and see what we can do with this cute observation. Define $(W_n)$ by
$$ W_n = \prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{4k^2}{4k^2 - 1}. $$
This partial products enter our story via the following lemma:

Lemma 2. There exists a constant $C > 0$ such that
$$ \left| D(x) - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sqrt{\frac{W_n}{2}} \frac{x^{2n}}{n!} \right| \leq C $$
for all $x \geq 0$.

Combining Lemma 1 and 2, we have
$$ \left| f(x) - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sqrt{\frac{W_n}{2}} p_n(x) \right| \leq Ce^{-x^2}, \qquad \text{where}\quad p_n(x) = \frac{x^{2n}}{n!}e^{-x^2}. $$
Now the last ingredient is the following abelian lemma, telling that if a sequence converges, then its "moving average" also converges to the same limit as the window slides to the infinity:

Lemma 3. (Abelian Theorem) Suppose a sequence of functions $p_n : \mathbb{R}_{\geq0} \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ satisfy the following properties:

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} p_n(x) = 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.
$\lim_{n\to\infty} p_n(x) = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$

Then for any convergent sequence $(c_n)$ in $\mathbb{C}$, we have
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n p_n(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} c_n. $$

Applying this lemma, we find that
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sqrt{\frac{W_n}{2}} p_n(x)
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{\frac{W_n}{2}}
= \sqrt{\frac{W}{2}}. $$
Therefore the desired conclusion follows from the squeezing lemma, provided all the lemmas are established. $\square$
Now it is time to supply the proof for the skipped parts.

Proof of Lemma 1. Define $D(x) = e^{x^2} f(x)$ and note that
$$ D'(x) = 2x e^{x^2} f(x) + e^{x^2} f'(x) = 2x D(x) + 1. $$
Solving this differential equation along with the initial condition $D(0) = 0$ using power series method, we obtain the desired result. $\square$

Proof of Lemma 2. For brevity, we write $a_n(x) = \frac{2^n}{(2n+1)!!} x^{2n+1}$, so that $D(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n(x)$. Then we note that
\begin{align*}
a_{n-1}(x)a_n(x)
= \frac{2^{2n-1}x^{4n}}{(2n-1)!!(2n+1)!!}
= \frac{P_n}{2} \left(\frac{x^{2n}}{n!}\right)^2.
\end{align*}
So by AM-GM inequality,
\begin{align*}
D(x)
&\geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_{n-1}(x) + a_n(x)}{2} \\
&\geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{a_{n-1}(x)a_n(x)} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sqrt{\frac{W_n}{2}} \frac{x^{2n}}{n!} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},
\end{align*}
establishing the lower bound for $D(x)$.
For the upper bound, note that
$$ \frac{a_n(x)}{a_{n-1}(x)} = \frac{2x^2}{2n+1} , $$
which is strictly decreasing in $n$. This means that $n \mapsto a_n(x)$ is unimodal. Let $N = N(x)$ be any maximizer, i.e.,
$$ N = N(x) \in \underset{n\geq 0}{\operatorname{argmax}} \, a_n(x). $$
Then solving the conditions $a_N(x) \geq a_{N-1}(x)$ and $a_N(x) \geq a_{N+1}(x)$ shows that $2N+1 \leq 2x^2 \leq 2N+3$. In particular, $N(x) \to \infty$ as $x\to\infty$. This unimodality of $a_n(x)$ also shows that $D(x)$ is bounded above as follows:
\begin{align*}
D(x)
&= \left( \sum_{k=1}^{N} a_{k-1}(x) \right) + a_N(x) + \left( \sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty} a_k(x) \right) \\
&\leq \left( \sum_{k=1}^{N} \sqrt{a_{k-1}(x)a_k(x)} \right) + a_N(x) + \left( \sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty} \sqrt{a_{k-1}(x)a_k(x)} \right) \\
&\leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sqrt{\frac{W_n}{2}} \frac{x^{2n}}{n!} + a_N(x)
\end{align*}
In light of this, it suffices to prove that $a_N(x)$ is bounded. However,
\begin{align*}
a_N(x)^2
= \frac{1}{2} \frac{(2x^2)^{2N+1}}{(2N+1)!!^2}
&\leq \frac{1}{2} \frac{(2N+3)^{2N+1}}{(2N+1)!!^2} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \prod_{k=1}^{N+1} \frac{2N+3}{(2N+3-2k)(2k-1)} \\
&\leq \frac{1}{2} \prod_{k=1}^{N+1} \frac{2N+3}{2N+1} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \frac{(1 + \frac{1}{2N+2})^{N+1}}{(1 - \frac{1}{2N+2})^{N+1}}.
\end{align*}
In the penultimate step, we utilized the fact that $(2N+3-2k)(2k-1)$ for $1 \leq k \leq N+1$ is minimized at the endpoints. Since this bound converges as $N\to\infty$, it there follows that $a_N(x)$ is bounded, completing the proof of Lemma 2. $\square$

Proof of Lemma 3. Its proof is quite standard, but we nevertheless include it for the sake of self-containedness. Write $c_{\infty}$ for the limit of $(c_n)$. Also, fix a positive integer $N$. Then
\begin{align*}
\left| \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n p_n(x) - c_{\infty} \right|
&= \left| \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (c_n - c_{\infty}) p_n(x) \right| \\
&\leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left|c_n - c_{\infty}\right| p_n(x) \\
&\leq \sum_{n=0}^{N} \left|c_n - c_{\infty}\right| p_n(x) + \left( \sup_{n > N} \left|c_n - c_{\infty}\right| \right) \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} p_n(x)\\
&\leq \sum_{n=0}^{N} \left|c_n - c_{\infty}\right| p_n(x) + \sup_{n > N} \left|c_n - c_{\infty}\right|
\end{align*}
Now taking $\limsup$ as $x \to \infty$, the assumption tells that $\left|c_n - c_{\infty}\right| p_n(x) \to 0$ for each $n$. Hence,
$$ \limsup_{x\to\infty} \left| \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n p_n(x) - c_{\infty} \right|
\leq \sup_{n > N} \left|c_n - c_{\infty}\right|. $$
Since the limsup does not depend on $N$, letting $N \to \infty$ shows that the limsup is zero, proving the desired claim. $\square$
